# How to determine the size of a pointsGrob (vs the one of a textGrob)?

Tags: r, r-grid

Why does determining the size (in mm, for example) of a points grob (`pointsGrob`) fail, but not for a text grob (`textGrob`)?

```
### puzzled about grobs (not) knowning how big they are:
require(grid)
convertUnit(grobWidth(textGrob("some tex")), "mm") # 16.93mm => fine
convertUnit(grobWidth(pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5)),  "mm") # 0mm => ?
convertUnit(grobWidth(pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, size=unit(3, "mm"))), "mm") ## still 0mm...
```

The reason why I am asking is: If you place a text grob and a points grob side-by-side, and change the value of `cex`, then suddenly the two grobs overlap (unwanted behavior).

Here is an example showing a similar prolem:

```
gt <- grobTree(pointsGrob(x=.5, y=.5,  gp=gpar(cex=4)),
               linesGrob(x=0:1, y=.5,  gp=gpar(cex=4)),
               pointsGrob(x=.5, y=.5,  gp=gpar(cex=1)))
pg <- packGrob(frameGrob(vp=NULL), gt,
               width = unit(1, "char"),
               height = unit(1, "char"))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(pg)
grid.rect(width=grobWidth(pg), height=grobHeight(pg), gp=gpar(col="red"))
```

The rectangle reveals that the grob width and height are not correct; `pg` does not "see" the size of the point with large `cex`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I imagine points are considered to have zero size. You could draw a circle instead

Comment: But a point can have many different forms (`pch`), so a solution based on a circle would only deal with `pch=1`.

Comment: the size of point symbols [has always mystified me](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-May/053512.html) to be honest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how to solve the problem of zero point size, presumably it would have to be defined in the internals of the grid source code at the C level.

However, I want to point out that regardless of the pointsGrob issue, the grobWidth and grobHeight are not defined for your packGrob / gTree and the approach would fail even if pointsGrob were replaced by a textGrob. 
You probably want to define a gTree of a new class, say "mygrob", and define your own widthDetails.mygrob and heightDetails.mygrob methods,

```
library(grid)

gt <- grobTree(linesGrob(x=c(0.2, 0.8), y=.5,  gp=gpar(col="grey", lwd=10)),
               textGrob("some label",  gp=gpar(cex=2)),
               cl = "mygrob")

widthDetails.mygrob <- function(x)
  do.call(max, lapply(x$children, grobWidth))


heightDetails.mygrob <- function(x)
  do.call(max, lapply(x$children, grobHeight))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
grid.rect(width=grobWidth(gt), height=grobHeight(gt), gp=gpar(col="red"))
```

Comment: Thanks, Baptiste. I thought that one of the major advantages of 'grid' is that I don't have to deal with the 'sizes' by myself, just pack the grobs together and things like their size etc. is automatically taken care of [otherwise, one could use base graphics instead]. So I assume your answer means "you have to take care of this yourself" (?)

Comment: For complex grobs such as gTree, it isn't always obvious how one should define the width/height. Someone has to define the calculations, and unfortunately grid doesn't have a default method (the obvious choice would be a "bounding box" enclosing all objects).

Comment: Indeed a "bounding box" for a (generally set up) gTree would be great. I assume this does not exist [in ggplot, for example] (otherwise you would have pointed me to the source)...

Comment: you can always ask Paul Murrell directly, he might have something.

Comment: do you know if he is on stackoverflow?

Comment: Thank you, Baptiste, indeed your approach makes much sense now ... though I think I had used the same `do.call(max, ...)` approach for `heightDetails.*()` as for `widthDetails()`. Further, I'm indeed wondering why there's not  (width|height)Details.gTree() default, and am going to propose one to Paul Murrell.

Comment: presumably the default isn't trivial to compute, e.g. when grobs aren't centred, not only the width but also the x position and angle matter for the visual "bounding box". It's certainly something better done internally at a low (C-) level, like the size of the points.

Comment: Baptiste, your answer does not use `pointsGrob(.... cex=4...)` and that is the crucial point. Also note that you copied the `linesGrob()` in which Marius accidentally used `gp=gpar(cex=4)` where it really has no effect. The big issue is with width/height of the pointsGrob() or rather the grobTree() constructed from the points*() and linesGrob().

Comment: @MartinMächler I've edited my post to clarify those points. I never claimed to have an answer but my point was too long for a comment; in fact, it should not have the tick mark!

Comment: Thank you @baptiste for the explanation and clarification. So, Marius, do unclick the tick..